# Как с помощью reduce свернуть массив, вернув определенную структуру

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

```
  [
        {
            "x": 6,
            "y": 20
        },
        {
            "x": 6,
            "y": 45
        },
        {
            "x": 7,
            "y": 1
        },
        {
            "x": 7,
            "y": 15
        },
        {
            "x": 7,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 7,
            "y": 19
        },
        {
            "x": 7,
            "y": 17
        },
        {
            "x": 7,
            "y": 2
        }
    ]
```

Помогите свернуть такой массив. На выходе должно получится `[{x: 6, y:65},{x:7, y:59}]` Т.е. нужно суммировать 'y' у одинаковых x

Comment: А почему именно так, мы должны залезть к вам в голову и прочитать?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно сложить все значения `y` в группах объектов, где `x` совпадает, можно так:

```js
const array = [
  { "x": 6, "y": 20 },
  { "x": 6, "y": 45 },
  { "x": 7, "y": 1 },
  { "x": 7, "y": 15 },
  { "x": 7, "y": 5 },
  { "x": 7, "y": 19 },
  { "x": 7, "y": 17 },
  { "x": 7, "y": 2 }
];

const sums = Object.values(array.reduce(
  (acc, { x, y }) => {
    acc[x] ??= { x, y: 0 };
    acc[x].y += y;
    return acc;
  },
  {},
));

console.log(sums);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш ответ очень помог!